# I am getting an error while connecting to mysql database

Tags: javascript, mysql

I am trying to input some data into a `mysql` database, but I can't connect to it.

*My code:*

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "yourusername",
  password: "yourpassword"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});
```

I have also installed mysql into my system by using `npm install mysql` in **cmd**. Whenever I try to execute the above code, I get this error:

```
C:\Users\Abhishek\Desktop\Data scraping\scraping.js:60
  if (err) throw err;
           ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1129:16)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\Abhishek\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (C:\Users\Abhishek\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (C:\Users\Abhishek\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:116:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Abhishek\Desktop\Data scraping\scraping.js:59:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1083:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1112:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:948:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:789:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:72:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  errno: -4078,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you turned on mysql ?

Comment: Please, make sure that your MySQL service is running locally on port `3306`.

Comment: No, how do I do that?

Comment: This is a driver you need to make sure you have MySQL service installed and running

Comment: Which os are you using ?

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-18-04 This if Ubuntu

Comment: you need to add the value of socket path to the config object `socketPath: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'`